# How to create a vector with components bigger than a number in numpy?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

For example, I have a vector like this:

```
v = np.array([2, 4, 1, 7, 9, 3, 5])
```

I want to compare each component to a number to obtain a new vector which components are bigger of equal to the number (in case if the original component is less). For the above example and `limit=3` the result should be:

```
np.array([3, 4, 3, 7, 9, 3, 5])
```

How can I do it with `numpy`?

Comment: Just `v[v < limit] = 3`

Comment: You can use [`np.where`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.where.html), namely `v = np.where(v < 3, 3, v)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply do

```
v[v <= 3] = 3
```

which gives you the desired output:

```
array([3, 4, 3, 7, 9, 3, 5])
```

Brief explanation:

```
v <= 3
```

creates a Boolean array

```
array([ True, False,  True, False, False,  True, False], dtype=bool)
```

and the command

```
v[v <= 3]
```

sets all values to `3` where this Boolean array evaluates to `True`.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use `numpy.clip`:

```
>>> np.clip(v, 3, None)
array([3, 4, 3, 7, 9, 3, 5])
```

The second argument is a *maximum*, but I've given it only a minimum.

This can also be provided with an `out` argument, in this case, if you supply itself as the target, it will work in-place:

```
>>> x = np.clip(v, 3, None, v)
>>> id(x), id(v)
(4357557104, 4357557104)
>>> v
array([3, 4, 3, 7, 9, 3, 5])
>>>
```

The docs:

> ```
> out : ndarray, optional
>     The results will be placed in this array. It may be the input
>     array for in-place clipping.  `out` must be of the right shape
>     to hold the output.  Its type is preserved.
> ```

This could potentially be useful if you are memory constrained (I believe no intermediate boolean array gets created).

Comment: On `arr = np.random.randint(0, 10, 1000000)` and for my comment vs in-place clipping: `30.3 ms ± 174 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)` vs `22.6 ms ± 1.88 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)`. Clipping wins on speed too :)

Comment: _However_ there is no difference in speed when I don't supply `out` as an argument, and I would think there's overhead in creating that intermediate boolean array... so I'm not confident that in-place `clip` doesn't also create a boolean array.

Comment: @roganjosh yeah, frankly, I find reading the `numpy` source-code difficult, so usually I'd lean on empirical evidence like this.